# On run app in android studio first stuck at Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... and after some time gives an exception

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-emulator, flutter-layout

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not download armeabi_v7a_debug.jar (io.flutter:armeabi_v7a_debug:1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408)
      > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/io/flutter/armeabi_v7a_debug/1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408/armeabi_v7a_debug-1.0.0-af51afceb8886cc11e25047523c4e0c7e1f5d408.jar'.
         > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 30s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```